anchor test error
vel@Iamprabha:~/web3/voting-app/anchor$ anchor test --skip-local-validator --skip-deploy
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.19s
Finished test profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.15s
Running unittests src/lib.rs (/home/vel/web3/voting-app/anchor/target/debug/deps/voting-bd3969dd6e10ac46)
Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!
Running test suite: "/home/vel/web3/voting-app/anchor/Anchor.toml"
Error: websocket error
console.warn
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
> 1 | import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
    | ^
  2 | import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
  3 | import { PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
  4 | import { Voting } from "../target/types/voting";

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/bigint-buffer/dist/node.js:10:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:10:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/nodewallet.ts:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (anchor/tests/votingapp.spec.ts:1:1)

RUNS  tests/votingapp.spec.ts
[2024-10-25T08:30:52.472184708Z INFO  solana_program_test] "voting" SBF program from target/deploy/voting.so, modified 30 minutes, 17 seconds, 20 ms, 358 µs and 353 ns ago
RUNS  tests/votingapp.spec.ts
FAIL  tests/votingapp.spec.ts (21.306 s)ana_program_test] Overriding account at AsjZ3kWAUSQRN
voting
✕ Initialize poll (160 ms)
● voting › Initialize poll
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

  19 |     const provider = new BankrunProvider(context);
  20 |
> 21 |     const votingProgram = new Program<Voting>(IDL, provider);
     |                           ^
  22 |
  23 |     await votingProgram.methods
  24 |       .initializePoll(

  at new Program (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/index.ts:295:44)
  at anchor/tests/votingapp.spec.ts:21:27
  at fulfilled (anchor/tests/votingapp.spec.ts:28:58)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        21.363 s, estimated 22 s
Ran all test suites.
